# SQL statement that repeats itself until there are no more results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below existing statement. It finds parts that exist within other builds. The problem is, my user wants to go further until there are no more results.

For example.

We look up where PartA is used.

We find it is used inside of PartB and PartC.

Then we want to run the query again to find where PartB is used and PartC.

If PartB is not used anywhere else (No results found), we want to return PartB as part of the results.

But if PartC is used somewhere else, we want to keep going until we get no result for each part.

I am not sure if this is even possible so I thought I would ask here.

```
select ms.contract site,
  ms.part_no,
  crar1app.INVENTORY_PART_API.GET_DESCRIPTION(ms.contract, ms.part_no) part_desc,
  ms.QTY_PER_ASSEMBLY,
  ms.PRINT_UNIT uom,
--  ms.ENG_CHG_LEVEL,
  crar1app.ENG_PART_REVISION_API.GET_PART_REV(ms.PART_NO, ms.ENG_CHG_LEVEL) rev,
  ms.EFF_PHASE_IN_DATE,
  ms.EFF_PHASE_OUT_DATE,
  ms.BOM_TYPE,
  ms.ALTERNATIVE_NO alt
from crar1app.MANUF_STRUCTURE ms
where ms.CONTRACT = nvl('&SITE','10')
  and ms.COMPONENT_PART = '&PART_NO'
  and  ms.EFF_PHASE_IN_DATE <= to_date(nvl('&EFF_DATE',to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')),'YYYY-MM-DD')
  and (ms.EFF_PHASE_OUT_DATE > to_date(nvl('&EFF_DATE',to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')),'YYYY-MM-DD')
    or ms.EFF_PHASE_OUT_DATE is null)
  and (ms.ALTERNATIVE_NO = 'ML' 
    or (select 1 from dual where  crar1app.MANUF_STRUCT_ALTERNATE_API.GET_OBJSTATE(ms.CONTRACT,ms.PART_NO,ms.ENG_CHG_LEVEL,ms.BOM_TYPE,'ML') in ('Plannable','Buildable')) IS NULL)
```

I have tried a few things but nothing close to what I am looking for.

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer, but the key search phrase you need to solve this on your own is "Recursive CTE".

Comment: Joel is correct, and your oracle might have a special function to do this recursion called CONNECT BY PRIOR

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table; the `INSERT` statements for your sample data; and the expected output for that sample data. If we don't know what you are starting with and what you want then trying to reverse engineer your code and work out the expectation from your description is going to be almost impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of options are available to you in a CONNECT BY query which lets you loop through a hierarchy, eg

```
SQL> create table parts as
  2  select empno part_num, mgr parent_part
  3  from scott.emp;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> select
  2    level,
  3    part_num,
  4    parent_part,
  5    sys_connect_by_path(part_num,'-') path,
  6    connect_by_isleaf
  7  from parts
  8  connect by prior part_num = parent_part
  9  start with parent_part is null;

     LEVEL   PART_NUM PARENT_PART PATH                           CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF
---------- ---------- ----------- ------------------------------ -----------------
         1       7839             -7839                                          0
         2       7566        7839 -7839-7566                                     0
         3       7788        7566 -7839-7566-7788                                0
         4       7876        7788 -7839-7566-7788-7876                           1
         3       7902        7566 -7839-7566-7902                                0
         4       7369        7902 -7839-7566-7902-7369                           1
         2       7698        7839 -7839-7698                                     0
         3       7499        7698 -7839-7698-7499                                1
         3       7521        7698 -7839-7698-7521                                1
         3       7654        7698 -7839-7698-7654                                1
         3       7844        7698 -7839-7698-7844                                1
         3       7900        7698 -7839-7698-7900                                1
         2       7782        7839 -7839-7782                                     0
         3       7934        7782 -7839-7782-7934                                1
```